# How to upload code to AtMega2560 using JTAG ICE 2.0

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega

Background : I'm used to code in Arduino(Uno, Mega, Esp32, Esp8266). But this time i have to code directly on AVR Atmega 2560 Chip.

I have AVR JTAG ICE 2.0 (like [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/191442783293?ru=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com%2Fsch%2Fi.html%3F_nkw%3D191442783293%26_rdc%3D1) one) and download several program such as CodeVision AVR, Atmel Studio 6.0 and 7.0. I can make hex file from CodeVision but i didnt know how to upload the code. How to do that?

(I work both on windows and linux)

Comment: A hex file is a juncture where various preceding and following flows cross paths, so even though you are not using Arduino in this project, you can actually use the same programming methods as Arduino typically uses - just run avrdude yourself.  One way to figure that out the specific invocation is to set the arduino tool to upload with a programmer and enable verbose output and run it to see what it does.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, would you like to explain the step on detail? I'm not sure about what to do..

Comment: What I'm saying is that you can learn how to do this for your non-Arduino project if you momentarily set the Arduino IDE for verbose output and to use your programmer, load some arduino code to the chip via the programmer, copy the resulting avrdude command line and modify as needed for your custom non-Arduino hex file.  It's easiest if you continue to use the avrdude install and configuration files provided by the Arduino suite rather than trying to discretely install them on their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using AVR Studio 4.0, try these steps:
[image]

[image]

[image][image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I Hope this will Help.

Comment: thanks for your explanation